# Excel VBA Printing Autofit issues

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel VBA print function that is called once for each sheet I want to print in my workbook

I cycle through the sheets in VBA and call this function.

```
Sub PrintSheet
  With ActiveSheet

    'lastRow is worked out here....

    'Autofit YTD and SLY
    .Columns("J:J").AutoFit
    .Columns("K:K").AutoFit

    'Autofit email column
    .Columns("F:F").AutoFit

    With .PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"

        .PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$" & CStr(lastRow)
    End With

    .PrintOut
 End With
End Sub
```

The issue I am having is that sometimes (random behaviour and not always the same sheet) the columns that I am autofitting stretch really wide forcing other columns off the page.  This is not data related as you can run the print routine again and it prints the same sheet which was previously stretching columns out fine.  I am trimming all column values in the sheet as they get inputted with VBA code in the first place

I have not been able to find any pattern with this behaviour apart from as I said the columns that stretch are the ones that are getting autofitted.

Any thoughts?

Comment: ....did my attempt help you?  (....it's nice to get a little feedback)

Comment: brill - thanks for the up-vote. It's a strange behavior - if you ever find out why it happens please come back to this Q&A and add in an explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have experienced this many times when using `autofit`; so I try to use it as little as possible now.

Things you can do:

1.Use a set width e.g if you know that column J will always be ok at 47 width then use `Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 47`
2. You could add some tests to the end of your sub-routine like so:

```
Sub PrintSheet()

With Excel.ActiveSheet

    'lastRow is worked out here....
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(Excel.xlUp).Row

    'Autofit YTD / SLY / email
    .Columns("J:J").AutoFit
    .Columns("K:K").AutoFit
    .Columns("F:F").AutoFit

    With .PageSetup
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = False
        .Orientation = Excel.xlLandscape
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.4)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.5)
        .RightFooter = "&P of &N"
        .PrintArea = "$A$1:$O$" & lastRow 'CStr(lastRow) <=== & does an implicit conversion
    End With

    'add three checks here <====
    '<==I've picked 100 out of thin air but you need to change this to a value which indicates that it has behaved badly
    If .Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth > 100 Then
        .Columns("J:J").ColumnWidth = 30  '<== you might want to amend 30
    End If
    If .Columns("k:k").ColumnWidth > 100 Then
        .Columns("k:k").ColumnWidth = 30
    End If
    If .Columns("f:f").ColumnWidth > 100 Then
        .Columns("f:f").ColumnWidth = 30
    End If

    .PrintOut

End With
End Sub
```